# how to make a variable select all when querying a database

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

Hey all im trying to query a database using if if/else statement and I want one option to select all results from a specific column in the database (in this case location) an the other option to only select items based on form input:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['indexSearchSubmit']))
{
    if ($_POST['locationList']=='allLocations')
        {
            $selectedLocations = '*';
        }
    else
        {
            $selectedLocations = $_POST['locationList'];                
        }

    foreach($_POST['industryList'] as $selected)
        {
            $selectedIndustries = $selected;

            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM currentListings WHERE location = '$selectedLocations' AND industry = '$selectedIndustries'");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo $row['industry'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $row['location'];
                    echo "<br>";
                }
        }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

?>

The bit im confused about is the selectedlocation ='' im unsure what to put in in order for it to return all results.

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What does `$selectedLocations` contain? Is it a list of ids or a mapping of values?

Comment: on the if part select locations doesnt contain anythign because im not sure what to put in there. on the else part it contains an array from a form in which the user has selected locations they are interested in

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do

```
if ($_POST['locationList']=='allLocations')
    {
        $l = 'IS NOT NULL';
    }
else
    {
        $l = " = '". $_POST['locationList'] . "'";
    }
```

and

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM currentListings WHERE location " . $l . "  AND industry = '$selectedIndustries'");
```

This way the query string will be either

```
"SELECT * FROM currentListings WHERE location IS NOT NULL  AND industry = '$selectedIndustries'"
```

OR

```
"SELECT * FROM currentListings WHERE location = '[xxx]'  AND industry = '$selectedIndustries'"
```

where [xxx] is the value of the selected option.

Comment: wghat does the is not null do?

Comment: What it does is what you want: it selects all rows where `location` is not null.

Comment: thanks just to ask as im a bit new what is the use of the  = " = ' on the else